# Calculate $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{1 + x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

The question is as follows:

Calculate $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{1 + x^2} dx$.

$\textbf{Some ideas:}$

We can use the fact that $\sin(\frac{x}{n}) \simeq \frac{x}{n} $.But then we find that

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{1 + x^2} dx \simeq \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{n  \times \frac{x}{n}}{1 + x^2} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \frac{ x }{1 + x^2} dx $

$ \hspace{9.1cm} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{n} \frac{ 2x }{1 + x^2} dx   $

$ \hspace{9.1cm} \text{take } x^2=y$

$ \hspace{9.1cm} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{ dy }{1 + y} $

$ \hspace{9.1cm} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\ln(y)}{2} $

$\hspace{9.1cm} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2)}{2} \mid_{0}^{n}$

$\hspace{9.1cm} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\ln(n^2)}{2} = +\infty$

But someone said me that the final result should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Can you please let me know where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: For one, where did that upper limit of $n$ come from? (But the real problem is that making that approximation inside the integral is not justified here.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks! I cannot understand your question? Can you please explain more? Can you please let me know what can we do else that approximation?

Comment: You went from $\int_0^\infty$ to $\int_0^n$ in the second equality... I guess you were reusing the $n$ for an improper integral? Actually, although I don't think taking the limit under the integral sign is fully justified, I think you're right that it diverges

Comment: It does diverge as $\log(n)$ just as you found.

Comment: @user510716 I think your friend might have meant the integral of  $n\sin^2(x/n)/(1+x^2)$ from $0$ to $\infty$ is $\pi/2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks! So you mean that my strategy of using approximation under the integral is correct?

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks! So you say that my strategy of using approximation under the integral and my calculation is correct?

Comment: @user510716 as a heuristic I think it's fine. But I can't call it rigorous.

Comment: @JackyChong If they used the same strategy on the integral you suggest they must have meant, they would get zero, not $\pi/2.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks! But why they would get zero?

Comment: @user510716 Such approximations should be justified. I guess here's a good exercise: show that the integral Jacky identifies as the one they must have meant comes out to $\pi/2.$

Comment: @user510716 (By they I meant you). Because $\lim _{n\to \infty} n\sin^2(x/n) = 0.$ (edit: I guess I actually used 'they' twice confusingly)

Comment: You could also try to set up a contour integral and see if you have an easier time with that.

Comment: @JackyChong Sorry, but are you sure that the integral of $n\sin^2(x/n)/(1+x^2)$ is $\pi/2$? I think that one is zero if we use the same approximation. As in that case $n\sin^2(x/n) \simeq \frac{x^2}{n}$ and then we can take $\frac{1}{n}$ out the integral and finally we will get zero as $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to zero as $ n \to \infty$? Am I right?

Comment: @user510716 No, the integral actually is $\pi/2.$ Precisely my point about needing to be careful bringing limits inside integrals. (Hint: change variables to $u=x/n$ and then bring the limit inside... it happens to be justified after the change of variables.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks! Yes I found it by getting help. For to see that we have to calculate $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(u)}{u^2} du$, which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but not easily!

Comment: @user510716 Yep, didn't say it'd be easy :). Incidentally, I find your original question easier to analyze and prove that it logarithmically diverges after the same change of variables (though I may just be being dense and missing a justification for attacking the original integral by taking the limit inside).

Answer (score 3):

This is too long to be in the comment section. The purpose of this post is to compute
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{n\sin^2\frac{x}{n}}{1+x^2}\ dx
\end{align}
exactly (not the limit). This is a harder way to show that the limit of my proposed revision of the problem is indeed $\pi/2$.

First, note that the integrand is integrable for all values of $n$. Next, observe
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{n\sin^2 \frac{x}{n}}{1+x^2}\ dx =&\ \frac{n}{2}\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx -\frac{n}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{\cos \frac{2x}{n}}{1+x^2}\ dx \\
=&\  \frac{n\pi}{4} - \frac{n}{4} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\exp(i\frac{2x}{n})}{1+x^2}\ dx. 
\end{align}

Now, using contour integration, we can show that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\exp(i\frac{2x}{n})}{1+x^2}\ dx = \pi e^{-2/n}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{n\sin^2\frac{x}{n}}{1+x^2}\ dx = \frac{n\pi}{4}\left( 1- e^{-2/n}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}ne^{-1/n}\sinh n^{-1}.
\end{align}
Finally, let us make the observation that for $n$ large we have that
\begin{align}
1-e^{-2/n} = \frac{2}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{n\sin^2\frac{x}{n}}{1+x^2}\ dx = \frac{\pi}{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align}
Thus, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we see that the integral approaches $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here I will show, more-or-less rigorously, that the original integral diverges logarithmically, as taking the limit inside the integral would suggest. (Mathematica actually gives a closed form solution in terms of hyperbolic inverse functions for the integral at finite $n$, but we'll pretend we don't know it.)

We do the change of variables $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x^2+1}\;dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+1/n^2}\;dx$$ and then split up the integral into $\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty$. In the second piece, the limit can be taken under the integral since the convergence is uniform on $(1,\infty)$ and we get $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} dx= \int_0^1 \sin(1/x)dx.$ The first piece we can rewrite as $$\int_{0}^1\frac{x}{x^2+1/n^2}\;dx +\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^2+1/n^2}\;dx. $$ The second integral no longer has a divergence at the origin, so the limit can be taken inside it. The first term is just $$ \frac{1}{2}\log(n^2+1).$$ So we finally get $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x^2+1}\;dx = \frac{1}{2}\log(n^2+1) + \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^2}+\sin(1/x)\right)\;dx  + o(1) \sim \log(n)$$